# Выходит ошибка 912 VK API. Почему?

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, бот, npm

Всем привет, помидорами не бросайте я только начинающий. Вообщем делаю бота, который должен получить данные записей сообщества. После слова "Парсить" начнет использоваться метод **wall.get**, в документации написано что можно использовать **токен пользователя**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я и сделал, когда у меня еще был токен сообщества выходила ошибка 27, но я еще мог дойти до слова ***Парсить***, а щас после слова ***Начать*** сразу ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и сама ошибка:
*Code №912 - This is a chat bot feature, change this status in settings.
Код №912 - Это функция чат-бота, измените этот статус в настройках*

P.s. Токен брал из [Vkhost.github.io](https://vkhost.github.io)

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, трассировку стека в вопрос (полную ошибку)

Comment: @nomnoms12, APIError: Code №912 - This is a chat bot feature, change this status in settings at SequentialWorker.execute (E:\OpenServer\domains\bot\node_modules\vk-io\lib\index.js:1670:39) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) { code: 912

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй токен вставить не сообщества, а админа
Либо Управление > сообщения > настройки для бота > возможности ботов: вкл

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).